# How to install sbt on Google Cloud compute engine VM?

Tags: sbt, google-compute-engine

I go through the steps mentioned in the debian package installation procedure on the official sbt website. These steps work locally on my Ubuntu machine, however the same steps do not work in a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM. When I run sbt, I get the following error:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.8 ...
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8
        ==== local: tried
          /home/<homedir>/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8!sbt.jar:
          /home/<homedir>/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/jars/sbt.jar
        ==== Maven Central: tried
          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.pom
          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8!sbt.jar:
          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.jar
        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
          https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
        ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried
          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found
                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected     error: 
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.pom

Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/sbt-0.13.8.jar

Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml

Server access Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/0.13.8/ivys/ivy.xml

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.8: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/<homedir>/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.8
```

Comment: I have similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not. Instead I currently use workarounds. For sbt run, I use the corresponding java -jar (...) command, and for building, I build on a local machine and send the jar to the VM.

Comment: thanks for the help. the must be away to fix this

Comment: I think it's solved. The question is a bit old.

I just tried with Ubuntu 16.04 and <http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html#Ubuntu+and+other+Debian-based+distributions>, it worked.